# Jasmine and Three.js asynchronous loading of Geometry

Tags: three.js, jasmine2.0

I try to use Jasmine to automatically test some functionality. The issue I have is that I want to test a class and for that need to load a geometry for all related tests. However due to asynchronous loading at time of execution of the tests the geometry has not been loaded and is undefined and thus test cases fail. Any idea how to make sure the geometry is loaded at time of test execution? Here the snipet to load the geometry

```
describe("Model Class", function() {
    var geometry; 

    beforeAll(function() {
        var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
        loader.load( '../tests/testdata/cube_big.stl', function ( geo ) {
            geometry = geo;
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the `beforeAll()` function takes one argument that you can call when async operations are complete:

```
beforeAll(function(done) {
    var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
    loader.load( '../tests/testdata/cube_big.stl', function ( geo ) {
        geometry = geo;
        done();
    });
});
```